# Match pattern with regex excluding certain characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to use regex to create substrings containing characters between "[" and "]" brackets but without the brackets themselves.

For example:

```
This is a String with [the substring I want].
```

The regex I use is as follows:

```
\[.*?\]
```

And it works fine except for the fact that it also includes brackets in the match. So the result I get is:

```
[the substring I want]
```

instead of

```
the substring I want
```

Yes, I can very easily get rid of the brackets afterwards but is there any way to not match them at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "lookarounds":

```
String test = "This is a String with [the substring I want].";
//                          | preceding "[", not matched
//                          |      | any 1+ character, reluctant match
//                          |      |  | following "]", not matched
//                          |      |  | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
the substring I want
```

Comment: A non-regex way would be:  System.out.println(test.substring(test.indexOf("[") + 1, test.indexOf("]")));

Comment: @Arqan you're welcome